# How to make a scroll view and there are 3 static tableviews inside it?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make an app with the function like WangYinews app.

It has a UIScrollView at the center and the UIScrollView has some UITableViews.

Now what I want to do is let user change some static UITableViews by slide the UIScrollView left or right.

Here is the effect as follow.

[image: like this app]

Here is the effect as follow.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want a paging scroll view which shows just one table view at a time? The image shows 4 table views, the title says 3 table views...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create 3-4 or more uitableview and add it on scroll view something like this:

```
[scrollView addsubView: table1];
[scrollView addsubView: table2];
```

And so on. And to differentiate these table views in delegate functions, you can use tag property like following:

```
table1.tag = 1;
table2.tag = 2;

//datasource methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

if(tableView.tag == 1){

      self.arrayForTable1.count;

}
if(tableView.tag == 2){

     self.arrayForTable2.count;

}

}
```

Hope it will give you an idea.